# Google cloud ML engine Batch Predict on GPU

Tags: google-cloud-ml

If I train with `standard_p_100` GPU's and am running some batch predict jobs with the trained models, is there a way for me to specify or request that the batch predictions be performed on GPU's? For comparison, the batch prediction for an epoch of training data seems to be taking 8-10x than it would during training time which leads me to suspect that it is not taking advantage of GPUs and i'm wondering if I have any control over speeding this up?

Comment: This is an alpha feature and requires whitelisting. Please reach out to cloudml-feedback@ to provide your project id for whitelisting.